# Enumerating wildcard imports in ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So, in ES2015 you can have:

```
// Module A
export const FOO = 0;
export const BAR = 1;

// Module B
import * as AExports from 'ModuleA';
console.log(AExports.FOO); // Prints 0
```

What's the official way to enumerate the exports of ModuleA at runtime?

```
import * as AExports from 'ModuleA';
// Are these values guaranteed to be something?
Object.keys(AExports); // If so, should I look at enumerable values?
[...AExports]; // Iterable values?
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(AExports); // Here?
```

As far as I can tell, the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) describes this as an ImportedBinding but I can't deduce anything more from that.

```
NameSpaceImport : * as ImportedBinding
Let localName be the StringValue of ImportedBinding.
Let entry be the Record {[[ModuleRequest]]: module, [[ImportName]]: "*", [[LocalName]]: localName }.
Return a new List containing entry.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important part of the spec in this case is that when you do

```
import * as foo from 'foo';
```

The `foo` variable's value is created at [section 15.2.1.16.4 step 12.b](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-moduledeclarationinstantiation) which creates a [`Module Namespace Exotic Object`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects), where [properties are the named exports](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects-ownpropertykeys) and [all properties are enumerable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects-getownproperty-p) so you are totally safe in using `Object.keys(foo)` to get the names of all of the named exports. The object is not iterable, so you will not be able to use an iterable spread, though you could use the proposed object spread syntax to copy the properties if you wanted. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` should work fine too.

Comment: Thanks for the extra links as well - They made it easier to understand the spec for next time.